# rowspan attribute does not span rows

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have the last row span the 3 rows of the previous row. However for some reason this is not working, I have rewritten the code several times in several different ways and cannot seem to get this to work:

CSS:

```
.div_walkthroughs_wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
}

#table_walkthroughs {
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
}

#table_walkthroughs td {
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="div_walkthroughs_wrapper">
        <table id="table_walkthroughs">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       column 1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       column 2
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       column 3
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="3">this row wont spant 3 rows</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you mean `<colspan>`. The table only has two rows.

Comment: yes. Attention to details. Sorry for wasting your time and thank you all for answering.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for the `colspan` property.

```
...
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">this row wont spant 3 rows</td>
</tr>
...
```